# ( CASE WHEN [date] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) is not working in my pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, isnull

I have written the follwoing code expecting to get 0's and 1's returned in the CASES but I get 1's and NULL's.

any suggestions to get 0's?

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME

SET @Today = FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))

SELECT*

FROM 
    (   SELECT e.[Employeenr],
           e.[Name],
           dc.[Code],
           c.[Description],
           (CASE WHEN ec.[date] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 'Date',
           (CASE WHEN dc.[creationdate] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 'Aanwezig'
FROM HR_Employee e
        left join HR_EmployeeDriverLicense d ON e.[Employeenr] = d.[Employee]
        left join DriverLicenseCategory dc ON d.[DriverLicenseCategory] = dc. 
        [DriverLicenseCategorynr]
        left join HR_EmployeeCertificate ec ON e.[Employeenr] = ec.[Employee]
        left join HR_Certificate c ON ec.[Certificate] = c.[Certificatenr]
        left join HR_Function f ON e.[Function] = f.[Functionnr]

     WHERE (e.[Date_out_of_employment] IS NULL 
        or e.[Date_out_of_employment] >= @today 
        or e.[Licensenumber] is not null) 
        and e.[LicenseExpireDate] is not null 
        and c.[Description] is not null 
        and ec.[Certificate] <> 5 
        and f.[Functionnr] = 1

 ) AS SRC 
 PIVOT
 ( MAX(Aanwezig) 
  FOR [Code] IN ([C], [C1], [C1E], [CE])) AS PivotTable 

  PIVOT
 ( MAX ([Date]) 
    FOR [Description] IN ([Kooiaap certificaat], [ADR Certificaat])) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are performing `PIVOT` you will get a `NULL` for rows, which do not have a value for the corresponding `PIVOT` column. Unfortunately, if you want to get `0` instead `NULL`, you need to add this logic in the final `SELECT` statement.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL([Kooiaap certificaat], 0), ISNULL([ADR Certificaat], 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `MAX` use `COUNT` function and `CASE WHEN` together.

Try below.

`COUNT(CASE WHEN AANWEZIG= 0 THEN NULL WHEN AANWEZIG= 1 THEN 1 END)`

Comment: THANKS! very usefull tip. count was the sollutions

Comment: ) AS SRC 
    PIVOT
    ( COUNT ([creationdate]) 
      FOR [Code] IN ([C], [C1], [C1E], [CE])) AS PivotTable 

  PIVOT
( COUNT ([Date] )
  FOR [Description] IN ([Kooiaap certificaat] , [ADR certificaat] ,[LZV certificaat])) AS PivotTable

Comment: You should share your solution in your question as well. It would be great if you could upvote. Thanks! @BramW

Comment: @BramW, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. You can also choose to up-vote the answer by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer.